# Classic asp not working in windows 10(IE11) machine

Tags: asp-classic

I have an application which is hosted on a Win 2012 server. The application is build in Classic asp. It works fine in **Win 7+IE11** machine after placing the meta tag. `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">`
But in **Win10+IE11** machine the application is not working and it is giving a blank page as the application works on SSO.
Any Suggestion on how to resolve it will be very useful.

Comment: can you try Firefox or Chrome? Under Windows 10 -- are you using old Internet Explorer 11 or Edge web browser?

Comment: You can use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`. Incase it is still giving problem use- html5shiv.min.js, respond.min.js. If still not working? Can you please share any page of code?